# Automate importing new libraries into Artifactory Ivy repository

Tags: ivy, artifactory

We are only using the basic feature of Artifactory for Ant-Ivy java projects. If we need new java libraries, we download JARs, craft ivy.xml, then "deploy" the bundle to our internal Artifactory repository. This has been working just fine. However, when we need a set of JARS that need many transitive dependencies, the tasks become very tedious. We don't use Maven and download JARS from Maven central does not provide ivy.xml file. I am wondering if there is an easy way to automate these process?

Thanks

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/ provides ivy XMLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/cea35843cb67b4b27d788dcbd55f0ef501e31e85/descriptors/pom2ivy/README.md) Artifactory user plugin which generates missing ivy.xml files from .pom files.
Please note that using a user plugin will require the professional version of Artifactory.